# from_logits in SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy loss function not working as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

After researching, my understanding of logit is that when `from_logits=True` output is not normalized (not a probability distribution) and when `from_logits=False` it is normalized by softmax function. So if `from_logtis=False` isn't it supposed to output probability distribution of class?

Here is my code:

```
(img_train, label_train), (img_test, label_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_train/255.0, label_train)).batch(32)
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_test/255.0, label_test)).batch(32)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28), batch_size=32)
flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10)(dense)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=10)

metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
for x, y in test_ds:
    logits = model(x)
    metric.update_state(y, logits)
metric.result()
```

printing out logits of last batch gives:

```
print(logits[0])

<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([  1.3062842 ,   2.253938  ,  -5.295599  ,   7.0740013 ,
       -17.184162  , -19.801863  ,   0.29550672, -81.3132    ,
        -9.149338  , -46.353527  ], dtype=float32)>
```

Now when I train it with `from_logits=False`

```
logit_false_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
logit_false_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
metric2 = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
for x, y in test_ds:
    false_logits = logit_false_model(x)
    metric2.update_state(y, false_logits)
metric2.result()
```

printing out last batch gives:

```
print(false_logits[0])

<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([-125.248  , -211.52843, -243.62004, -230.45828, -336.3651 ,
       -369.41864, -177.14006, -871.6252 , -401.76608, -529.4581 ],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: I believe that you would need to make the output layer a softmax function in the latter case, setting from_logits=False does not modify the model -- it just tells the loss function to treat it as if it does have a softmax at the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Softmax` activation function if you are using `from_logits=False` (which is default `from_logits=False` if not defined) to get the output probability distribution of the class.

```
tf.Tensor(
[1.2676346e-01 1.1662615e-02 1.2230438e-03 8.4634316e-01 6.9824701e-08
 9.0843132e-06 1.2575756e-02 2.9462583e-18 1.4229250e-03 5.9792920e-13], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
```

`Logits` are the unnormalized outputs of a neural network.
`Softmax` is a normalization function that squashes the outputs of a neural network so that they are all between 0 and 1 and sum to

So when you do not use the `Softmax` activation function and use `from_logits=True` or `from_logits=False`, this will give the unnormalized logits of the tensors as output.

```
tf.Tensor(
[  2.1156607  -1.1930232  -3.6891053   3.455227   -9.048524   -5.6176786
   0.9181027 -70.903275   -2.887693  -38.01756  ], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
```

Please check [this](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/12d3e6bfa7b46839c606bd8a3f5d27ce/from_logits.ipynb) gist for your reference.